# Passing multiple parameters to index controller using CodeIgniter-like MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am just beginning to learn PHP, so I apologize if this is a basic question. I am using what I understand to be a CodeIgniter-like MVC framework (NOT CI though - a homegrown framework)

I am trying to pass two parameters to my index controller, each of which will display a different error message. The errors are generated from two individual post functions (i.e., if user's log in is incorrect and if email already exists at sign up).

```
public function index($error1=NULL, $error2=NULL) {

$this->template->content = View::instance('v_index_index');
$this->template->content->error1 = $error1;
$this->template->content->error2 = $error2;

echo $this->template;

}
```

What I am observing is that the only error displayed is the parameter that appears in the parentheses first (e.g., at index/index/error2 the error1 message is displayed). I've already tested the logic for determining the error type, so I know that is correct and believe it must have something to do with the above.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: My question is: why when I redirect to /index/index/error2 does the error1 message still show? Basically, is what I am trying to do above not possible?

Comment: because first parameter in function is always `$error1`. Even if you do `$controller->index( $error2 = 'error2' );` the value will still be assigned to `$error1` withing that method. Also, as a side note, if you are new to PHP and OOP in general, please do not use CodeIgniter as source of your studies.

Comment: Hi teresko, Thanks for the follow up. Unfortunately, within the course I am taking, we must use this framework.

Comment: I would have this sort of course. I would ask the teacher if i can make a presentation about concepts and practices that are used in CodeIgniter (or any Rails-like framework) .. and spend an hour or so, detailing each bad practice, stupid design decision and misinterpretation of patterns, that it contains.